# How does IntelliJ compile Android Projects?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

So I'm trying to move my team's project from using the built in IntelliJ android package builder to Android Maven.

The thing I've noticed so far though is that it seems that if there are malformed 9 patch images, IntelliJ can ignore these issues and compile and deploy the application just fine while using Android Maven on the command line.

So the question I have is that can someone explain how IntelliJ packages 9 patch images into a deployable Android application. Is it using aapt? Is there a more direct way to simulate Intellijs android package builder to the command line?

Thanks

Comment: Try [12.0.2 build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP). If it doesn't help, [submit a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Am I trying to make IntelliJ fail? Otherwise it seems that it would just mask the problem.